# Direct URL to a template via plugin

Tags: plugins, redirect

I'm trying to create a "profile page" of sorts for users that I want to use the URL structure:

`www.domain.com/profile/USERNAME`

The system does **NOT** user the default WordPress users.

I've not attempted this yet as I've got no idea where to start! I'd prefer it if this page wasn't a Wordpress "Page" and I'd like for it to be created via my plugin's `profile.php` file (That contains the `profile` class). The username is stored in the site's `SESSION` so it doesn't need any variables. I just need to link a URL to a template without using WordPress pages, really :P

I'm not sure what information to provide so if there's something I've missed please let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really isn't the best use for wordpress. You are better off creating a custom post type called "profile" (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type or use a plugin like PODS) and then the URL rewrites are all done for you. You can enable / disable the archive page so that domain.com/profile lists all profiles or not at all.

Then add post meta (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) to your custom post type for extra fields you may want. I would recommend using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) for this. ACF is a great tool for rapidly creating advanced meta fields for specific scenarios.

In any case, don't waste your time custom cowboy-coding your own object when WordPress can do it already with alot less code. It's less work for you in the long-run.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll stick to doing it the WordPress way :)